# An item with the same key has already been added in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, collections

The error is not new, but the source of my error is not typical.
I had a code which compiles in Tech.CodeGenerator dll.

```
{
    double d = 0;

    var linq = from r in table.AsEnumerable()
    group r by new
    {
        _short_date = Convert.ToString(r.Field<object>("short_date")),
        _version = Convert.ToString(r.Field<object>("version")),
    } into seq
    select new
    {
        seq.Key._short_date,
        seq.Key._version,
        _value = Double.TryParse(seq.FirstOrDefault().Field<object>("value").ToString(), out d) ? Convert.ToString(seq.Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Field<object>("value")))) : Convert.ToString(seq.FirstOrDefault().Field<object>("value")), 
    };

    DataTable res = table.Clone();

    foreach (var row in linq)
    {
        res.Rows.Add(
        row._short_date,
        row._version,
        row._value);
    }
    return res;
}
```

I can't understand where here I add a key to Dictionary? And how to fix it?

```
var assembly = CodeGenerator.CreateCode<DataTable>(code.ToString()
```

error happens here, so I can't exactly say the row

Comment: Would be good to include exact exception message together with full stack trace.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?